# swift How to send &nil to func?

Tags: swift, null

```
func setupCircular(circularLayer:inout CAShapeLayer?){
    if (circularLayer == nil) {
        circularLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    }else{

    }
}
setupCircular(circularLayer: &nil)
```

how to write？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a value as an `inout` parameter in Swift. You need to create a variable of type `CAShapeLayer`, assing it a `nil` value and use that as the input parameter to your function.

```
func setupCircular(circularLayer:inout CAShapeLayer?){
    if (circularLayer == nil) {
        circularLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    }else{

    }
}

var circ: CAShapeLayer? = nil
setupCircular(circularLayer: &circ)
```